# 3d Image gallery with Next and previous button - Vuforia Virtual Button

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am creating a 3d image gallery with virtual buttons. Presently using the virtual button example from vuforia site, I am able to implement each button for a single image. 
I want to create only two buttons to navigate with virtual button. How Can i go with this.

Comment: @Theodor Solbjørg is there any sample code or app have this facility? I need some guidance for gallery view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Below code is not tested, but should be simple to drop in to a C# script and the editor will point out what warnings you might get and suggest an easy fix.

```
List<Texture> MyImageList = new List<Texture>();
int imageIndex = 0;

void OnGUI() {
   GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width, Screen.height), MyImageList[imageIndex]);
   if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,80,10), "Prev")) {
      Prev();
   }
   if(GUI.Button(new Rect(200,10,80,10), "Next")) {
      Next();
   }
}

void Next() {
     if(imageIndex < MyImageList.Count)
        imageIndex++; else imageIndex = 0;
}

void Prev() {
     if(imageIndex > MyImageList.Count)
        imageIndex--; else imageIndex = MyImageList.Count;
}
```

its not a virtual button as such, but using a global list indexer is the best option, as the above demonstrates .